# Link between standard convolution and Day convolution

Tags: ct.category-theory, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, convolution

There is a notion of convolution product between two functors called "Day convolution". (See here [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution) for instance) I know that the definition of this notion is inspired by the discrete convolution $$(f\star g)(k)=\sum_{n+m=k}f(n)g(m).$$ But how about the "continuous" convolution ? I mean, can we obtain the traditional convolution $$(f\star g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)g(y)dy$$ as a particular case of Day convolution with specific categories and functors ? Or at least some links? One difficulty that seems to appear is that we need to consider "convolvability" conditions for the standard convolution product that we don't have with the discrete one.

Comment: I am reasonably, though not absolutely, sure that the word should be "convolvabilty", not "convolability", although it has been over 20 years since I did any Latin...

Comment: You're absolutely right, I correct this.

Comment: Have you heard about Lawvere distributions? I think this make the link.

Comment: I have never heard about it but a generalization of Schwartz Distribution is really interesting for me. Thank you !